# Is it possible to have object of some class as class property as other class in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am trying make a simple agent and environment class in MATLAB 2014.

I am trying to have the object 'a' of Agent class as one of the properties of the Environment class. I have initialized the object in the Environment class constructor, but whenever I am trying the access the methods of Agent class using this object A, I am getting warning as:

> "Confusing function call. Did you mean to reference property 'a'?"

Here is my Environment class and Agent class. How do I call method of Agent class from `interact_with_agent_function` directly like we call in JAVA?

```
classdef Environment < handle
    properties (Constant = true)
        V = 0.5;
        T = 1;
    end

    properties (SetObservable= true)
        A;
        B;
        a;
    end

    methods
        function obj = initialize(obj, A, B)
            obj.A = A;
            obj.B = B;
            a = Agent();
        end

        function act = call_agent(obj)
            act = agent_function(a, obj.A, obj.B, obj.V, obj.T); 
        end

        function action = interact_with_agent(obj)
            action = obj.call_agent();
        end
    end
end

classdef Agent < handle
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        action;
    end
    methods      
        function action = agent_function(obj, A, B, v, t)
            obj.action = A + v * t * ((B - A) / norm(B - A));
            action = obj.action;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want to refer to a member property, you must be explicit and use `obj.a = Agent()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is as follows:

- in the class definition, you created a variable (property) of your Environment class: lowercase `a`
- in the `initialize` method, you create a local variable `a`, which is removed after the function finished. You should use `obj.a = ...` to save the Agent() in the object.
- in the `call_agent` you use an uninitialised local variable `a` as first input. If you mean to refer to the `a` property of your class; use `obj.a` instead

On top of that, it might be useful to know that matlab has a default initialisation function for it's classes, which matches the name of your class; in your case this would be `function obj = Agent(obj)` and `function obj = Environment(obj)`; see also https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html for more information on classes in matlab.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your classes this way:

```
classdef Environment < handle
    properties (Constant = true)
        V = 0.5;
        T = 1;
    end

    properties (SetObservable= true)
        A;
        B;
        a;
    end

    methods
        % Replace here the init function using the Matlab Constructor 
        function obj = Environment(obj, A, B)
            obj.A = A;
            obj.B = B;
            obj.a = Agent(); % Call the Agent constructor here
        end

        function act = call_agent(obj)
            % Calling agent_function will automatically put a as the first argument
            act = obj.a.agent_function(obj.A, obj.B, obj.V, obj.T); 
        end

        function action = interact_with_agent(obj)
            action = obj.call_agent();
        end
    end
end

classdef Agent < handle
    properties (SetObservable = true)
        action;
    end

    methods      
        % Create Constructor
        function obj = Agent()
            obj.action = [];
        end

        function action = agent_function(obj, A, B, v, t)
            obj.action = A + v * t * ((B - A) / norm(B - A));
            action = obj.action;
        end
    end
end
```

I don't know why you are using two function to use the property `a`.
It is possible to call the function `agent_function` directly in the function `interact_with_agent`.

Anyway if you really want to code this way, you should set the function `call_agent` as static using: `methods (Static, Access = private)`. Like this, the only way to access to the property `a` will be to use the function `interact_with_agent`